# Showing html data from database to front end in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have upgraded my application from asp.net to mvc4. I am using html5 and displaying data in an html table. My database column contains html tags, but it is getting rendered as a plain text. Please help.

**

```
> Removable hard drive carrier only (DataPort)<html><br><b><font color
> ="red"> Part 444873-001 is no longer supplied. Please order the replacement, 580620-001</font></b></br></html>
```

**

Above line is a sample of how my data gets displayed in the column. I want to make the html tags to be rendered as html itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you render your model data, use the `Html.Raw()` helper to render the HTML data unencoded.  Razor automatically encodes HTML inputs in order to help prevent XSS attacks on websites.

```
<td>@Html.Raw(Model.MyProperty)</td>
```

Comment: No problem!  As a note of caution, the Html.Raw() helper should only be used when you trust the input in order to not circumvent the built in protections against user input :)